# limited connectivity from one computer, internet access on others

Tags: windows-7, wireless-router

I have a computer where the WLAN says limited connectivity.

The Wireless USB WLAN adaptor says limited connectivity, and the internal wifi also (though I haven't tested the internal wifi for a while so maybe it was bad before).  But the wireless USB WLAN adaptor was and is fine just not in that computer.

The router is fine, the internet light shows, and another computer can connect and browse fine. And my smart "phone" can connect and browse fine.

Currently I only have one WLAN USB adaptor to test with. But it works fine in another computer.

I tried a bat file with all these commands and restarted but still no luck

`ipconfig /flushdns, nbtstat -R, netsh int ipv4 reset all, netsh int ipv6 reset all, netsh winsock reset, netsh winsock reset catalog`

I checked it's not set to assign static ip. It's not. It's assigning a 169 ip.

It asks for the security password, then says "connecting to the network is taking longer than usual" then says "limited connectivity" or "limited access"

The router's log looks not useful, it doesn't seem to show any log of successful or unsuccessful connections. Netgear WNDR 4500   I have been connecting and disconnecting, both unsuccessfully from the comp that can't,  and successfully from the comp that can, and i've been doing this for the last half an hour and the last log even after refreshing, is half an hour ago . So the router is not logging this.

I tried ipconfig /release, ipconfig /renew.  I tried right click and diagnose.

It's not fixing it.

I got a list of wireless networks, checked it was WPA2 AES

I tried uninstalling the driver. properties..configure..uninstall.  And reinstalled the driver. Still same issue.

And interestingly a message came up saying the driver didn't install correctly. Though I see nothing in device manager saying that. And if I right click and then go to properties..configure,..general tab, it says 'the device is working properly'.  And just now I tried install the driver it didn't say that it didn't install correctly. And so it appears the driver installed fine but still same issues connecting.

I do wonder whether if I had a DDWRT router or tomato router, i'd get more log info.

**Added**
(I had since tried a few things which i'll mention here and I have since solved it and will post the solution)

The problems seemed to start when I installed npcap or tried to. I see npcap loopback adaptor listed.  (there's a hint there).

Things I tried. I had tried to connect to a wireless router in starbucks and got the same error. And my mobile phone had connected to my wireless router. And ('just' tried it) turns out my LAN doesn't work either.. and I 'think' my LAN was fine before.

So whatever it is, it made all my network  adaptors not work. And no internet access.

I tried in device manager right click and uninstall and scan.. thus reinstallign the driver. no luck. Not surprising since my LAN didn't work either and it affeted all network adaptors.

I was also sometimes getting a message that my "wireless network connection doesn't have a valid IP configuration" from the troubleshooter

Comment: can you get me a list of installed programs on the PC that this occurs on? I filed in issue on github, the creator says that this doesn't happen on several machines he owns, but that VPN, virus scanners, etc can mess with Npcap and windows. I think if you get me a list of your installed programs, I can cross-reference it with mine, and hopefully get to the bottom of this.

Comment: see https://github.com/nmap/nmap/issues/373 basically once I uninstalled all software from the company "Avaya" (corporate phone integration software) everything worked as expected with no workarounds necessary. I'm pretty happy with that since I'm allowed to remove that software, and I never need it. Maybe you have a similar program installed that is causing the issue?

Answer (score 3):

The solution was to uninstall npcap

My problems had begun when I installed that and ended when  I uninstalled it.

It requires a windows security update which I haven't installed yet 'cos I lack hdd space to install that windows security update. I might try npcap again in future 'cos I want it for wireshark to see 127..1

Answer (score 3):

> I have a computer where the WLAN says limited connectivity.
>
> ...
>
> The problems seemed to start when I installed npcap or tried to. I see npcap loopback adaptor listed. (there's a hint there).

I'm positive this is a problem with Npcap. I'm not sure if it happens on every machine, but it has happened to 3 entirely different Windows 7 laptops I have.

I also have a temporary workaround so you don't have to uninstall Npcap, you will lose somethings however.

You need to use 'npcap-nmap-0.06-r4', the latest version 'npcap-nmap-0.07' won't allow you to do step 4 below.

1. Go to network and sharing center and click on 'Change Adapter Settings' on the left.
2. Find you Wi-Fi interface in the list, and right click and select 'Properties'.
3. Uncheck 'Npcap Packet Driver (NPCAP)' and 'Internet Protocol Version 6' (TCP/IPv6)
4. Click 'OK'.
5. Find you Wi-Fi interface in the list, and right click and select 'Properties'.
6. Click 'Configure'.
7. Go to the 'Advanced' tab.
8. Select '802.11n Channel Width for band 2.4', and set the 'Value' to 'Auto'.
9. Go to the 'Power Management' tab.
10. Uncheck the 'Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power' item.
11. Click 'OK'.
12. Restart your machine, and you should be good now. If you use any other wireless adapter, you need to repeat the above steps for that adapter. The same applies if you reinstall this wireless interface's driver for any reason.

Answer (score 0):

I could've tried safe mode it may have been revealing.. but I didn't..

And Computer Management → Event Viewer → Applications and Services logs → Microsoft → Windows → WLAN-Autoconfig will tell you want the adapter is doing.

It's not entirely clear what fixed it.

I got another USB wireless adapter, and that first said the driver didn't install correctly, but then I installed the `.EXE` and went to device manager, saw the yellow exclamation mark, got it to search for a driver and it  found the one I'd just installed, and so that installed the new USB wireless adapter. But still, limited connectivity.

I tried turning the windows firewall OFF - didn't seem to help.

I then tried ending some processes.  Things like `flvga_tray.exe`, `hamachi-2-ui.exe`,  `vmware-tray.exe`.

I don't know if any of those made any difference as now I have internet access then I tried restarting, and I still have those - and internet access.

I tried an option to ensure the wireless network card had preferred networks set. As when I clicked diagnose it sometimes seemed to point to that.

I think when this all happened, I tried tethering my phone and first it worked, then I got limited connectivity.

My firewall seemed to have turned back up.

Beforehand, attempts at diagnose had failed.

This time though the breakthrough came, and inexplicably

[image]

So after fiddling around, suddenly diagnose managed to find it.

Answer (score 0):

The latest Npcap 0.06 doesn't require any windows security updates to be installed and will work on all Windows from Vista to Win10.

Please try the installer at:

https://github.com/nmap/npcap/releases

---

**UPDATE:**

This issue should have been fixed in latest Npcap `0.10 r15`. Please try it at: https://github.com/nmap/npcap/releases